# SQLite3 and limiting the number of results

Tags: c, sqlite, limit

Is there a clean way to limit the number of hits from an SQLite3 `SELECT` statement?

For example, I might query with `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name='Smith';` realising I could encounter thousands of hits. I'd like SQLite3 to give me say the first 10 it encounters and then terminate the query. How do I do this?

If SQLite3 does not provide this immediately, is there anything I can edit in the SQLite3 source code from which I can rebuild?

Assume I'm in an environment where I have only one thread and I'd like control back in a reasonable time.

Comment: @All: Thanks - I'd like to accept each of your answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for the `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name='Smith' LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 4):

See the [SELECT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) syntax: there is a `LIMIT` keyword:

```
select * from sometable where .... limit 10;
```

Look at the `OFFSET` too, can be helpful for paging results. (Also these are often combined with an `ORDER BY` clause if you want consistent results across queries.)

Answer (score 3):

From the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> The LIMIT clause is used to place an upper bound on the number of rows returned by a SELECT statement. Any scalar expression may be used in the LIMIT clause, so long as it evaluates to an integer or a value that can be losslessly converted to an integer. If the expression evaluates to a NULL value or any other value that cannot be losslessly converted to an integer, an error is returned. If the LIMIT expression evaluates to a negative value, then there is no upper bound on the number of rows returned. Otherwise, the SELECT returns the first N rows of its result set only, where N is the value that the LIMIT expression evaluates to. Or, if the SELECT statement would return less than N rows without a LIMIT clause, then the entire result set is returned.