# Fetching data from SQLite and want to get only the last value of column id

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am fetching data from SQLite and want to get only the last value of column id in XCode.The code is

```
NSString *selquery = @"select id from watchlists";
if (self.uid != nil) {
    self.uid = nil;
}
self.uid = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:selquery]];
NSString *valvar;

valvar = [_uid lastObject];

NSNumber *custval = [_uid valueForKey: @"@lastObject"];
NSString *imgval1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%s",custval,"1"];
NSLog(@"%@", imgval1);
```

Please tell me how can I get only the value because by using the above code I am getting array with last value of id.

Comment: What library do you use for: dbManager

Comment: Well, usually you would limit the fetch results to 1 in the SQL query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329032/sqlite3-and-limiting-the-number-of-results

Comment: how to get anly one value it is giving the lastvalue in the array i donot want it in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this your case, try this it **maybe** help you

```
NSArray *temp=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    NSArray *temp0ne=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:temp];
   // NSString *tmmp=[temp0ne lastObject];
    NSArray *finalStr=[uid lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary is---->%@",[finalStr lastObject]);
```

Output:

```
3_1
```

**EDIT**

```
NSArray *temp=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"(1)",@"(2)",@"(3)", nil];
    NSArray *temp0ne=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:temp];
    NSString *tmmp=[temp0ne lastObject];
    NSString *final=[tmmp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    final=[final stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    NSString *imgval1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%s",final,"1"];
    NSLog(@"%@", imgval1);
```

I don't know is this correct way or not try this....otherwise have look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199300/iphone-ios-sqlite3-not-able-to-get-last-id-value-in-table)

Comment: the array iam getting is from database by fetching data                                                                    (
        (
        1
    ),
        (
        2
    ),
        (
        3
    ),
        (
        4
    ),
        (
        5
    ),
        (
        6
    )
)

Comment: ok..use your database code with second array..i have done simply for your case

Comment: how you set your id column autoincreement ah?show us fetching code?

Comment: NSString *selquery = @"select id from watchlists";
    if (self.uid != nil) {
        self.uid = nil;
    }
    self.uid = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:selquery]]; Here UID is NsARRAy

Comment: i am asking database code?what is this self.dbManager?you have array within array...

Comment: yes @property (nonatomic, strong) DBManager *dbManager;

Comment: -(NSArray *)loadDataFromDB:(NSString *)query{
    // Run the query and indicate that is not executable.
    // The query string is converted to a char* object.
    [self runQuery:[query UTF8String] isQueryExecutable:NO];
    
    // Returned the loaded results.
    return (NSArray *)self.arrResults;
}

Comment: why are you casting here return (NSArray *)self.arrResults?what is self.arrResults?and show runQuery method?

Comment: it is returning in the form of array and iam desplaying it in table cells

Comment: that is why your database id column coming like this  ( ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 ) )...while creating database how you set id column?if it is autoincreement,it should come like this 1,2,3,4,5...see my edited code..  show runQuery method?

Comment: It is an array under array please tell how can i get the value of the array under array.It can solve the issue.

Comment: NSArray *finalStr=[uid lastObject];
    NSLog(@"dictonarry is---->%@",[finalStr lastObject]);

Comment: super pa..how did you change?

Comment: NSString *selquery = @"select id from watchlists";
    if (self.uid != nil) {
        self.uid = nil;
    }
    self.uid = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:selquery]];
    NSArray *valvar;
    
    valvar = [_uid lastObject];
    
    NSString *imgval1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%s",[valvar lastObject],"1"];
    NSString *imgval2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%s",[valvar lastObject],"2"];
    NSString *imgval3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%s",[valvar lastObject],"3"];
    NSLog(@"%@", imgval1);
    NSLog(@"%@", imgval2);
    NSLog(@"%@", imgval3);

Comment: I will take the lastobject of the lastobject and it worked for me perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your code structure hehe. Try this:

```
NSString *selquery = @"select id from watchlists";
if (self.uid != nil) {
    self.uid = nil;
}
self.uid = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:selquery]];

NSNumber *custval = [_uid objectAtIndex:[_uid count]-1];
```

*

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@",custval];

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"("
                                 withString:@""];
NSString *finalCustval = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@",str];

finalCustval = [finalCustval stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")"
                                 withString:@""];
```

*

```
NSString *imgval1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%s",finalCustval ,"1"];
NSLog(@"%@", imgval1);
```

**UPDATE**

try adding the ones with *.

Comment: the output is   (
    6
)_1
I want only 6_1 not()

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check. Sorry I can't remember the short method. hehe

Comment: The thing replacing ( with "" is not valid because we want to concatenate it with number but the output is showing line break and the concatenation is done in the next line. IF you can concatenate a nuber with it then it will help me. By the way thanks for showing interest.

Comment: Do another string replacement. imgval1 = [imgval1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                 withString:@""];